# Issue in picker in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am using **`IQActionSheetPickerView`** in my project.For single picker it ask for **`NSArray`** like below

```
[picker setTitlesForComponents:@[@[@"First", @"Second", @"Third", @"Four", @"Five"]]];
```

but i have a array which gets value from server so can't make it static.So i have used a NSMutableArray whose values are fetched from server & added to array so how can i use dynamic array in picker.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: add that server values array to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems too obvious but I think your question is how to pass the `NSMutableArray` filled with the values from the server to the picker.

```
NSMutableArray *serverData = ... // values from the server
[picker setTitlesForComponents:@[ serverData ]];
```

Is that what you are asking for? I'm assuming you have one array for one component.

Comment: Yes.But you look above how is the format required.Where as i have NSmutableArray with string values

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In my answer, if you put strings inside the `serverData` array, you end up with the same data structure as the hardcoded list in your question. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Ok i will check.Thanks